# Predict with TensorFlow MNIST for Experts

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the TensorFlow MNIST for Experts tutorial, but I do not know how to get the trained network to predict a new set of data.

Below is my code: I have all the lines in [TensorFlow MNIST for Experts tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/) and I imported a csv file with pandas as dataframe testt.

```
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
feed_dict = {x: testt[0], keep_prob:1.0}
classification = y_conv.eval(y, feed_dict)
print(classification)
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-96dfe9b26149> in <module>()
      2 y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
      3 feed_dict = {x: testt[0], keep_prob:1.0}
----> 4 classification = y_conv.eval(y, feed_dict)
      5 print(classification)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    573 
    574     """
--> 575     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    576 
    577 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   3627                        "`eval(session=sess)`.")
   3628   else:
-> 3629     if session.graph is not graph:
   3630       raise ValueError("Cannot use the given session to evaluate tensor: "
   3631                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'graph'
```

Please help. I am not sure how to properly call the trained network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to get the output of y with a `sess.run` call after your training loop:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(1000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

    logits = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: test_data})
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
    print(pred)  # or print(tf.argmax(pred, dimension=1)) for the index
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Comment: No problem, you can retrieve any value in the graph like this. Weights, loss, etc.